# Discord.js read client bot token from a file rather than hard-coded

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to be able to read the `client.login(BOT_TOKEN);` dynamically from a file/database, but this is getting executed before my file read function finishes executing.

```
BOT_TOKEN = '';

if(BUILD_PROFILE == 'dev'){
    filesystem.readFile('./../devToken.txt',  'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
        BOT_TOKEN = data;
    })
}

client.login(BOT_TOKEN);
```

This is the error I'm getting in logs - I have double checked the file and it's console.log(data) shows the right token, but it's not being applied
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you place your token in an ENV file.
I also think you should copy your token directly from your bot's bot page on discord and pasting it directly.

You console.log'd the `data` was it the right token?

Comment: yes the `data` was displaying the right token. what is this env file? how do I copy the token from the discord developer portal? I essentially have 2 tokens for 2 different bots, is it possible to do that? the reason I wanted to hide my token/account credentials is so I could public my github repo

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way to do this would be to have a config.js file in your main bot folder, and set out the

```
{
token: “token-here”
}
```

Then, in your main.js file, require the config file as a variable, then at your ‘`bot.login`’, just do ‘`bot.login(config.token)`’

You can also have your prefix set in this file too, allowing a user to possibly change your command prefix in the future

Additionally, you could use a SQLite database, that saves your token - you have to have the SQLite npm library, from https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite here, but it is very simple to set up, if anyone needs help here, add my discord Proto#4992

n.m. SQLite databases also will come in useful when/if you want to set up a currency system in the future.